# Samba Windows Share error: "NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED" - Missing usershares

Tags: networking, samba

EDIT: The problem actually turned out to be a missing file error. Still can't fix that :/ The missing file is `/var/lib/samba/usershares/public`

EDIT2: Can't even access the server itself. Googled and found the answer. It's down there /

Basically, title says it all, but here's my `smb.conf` (without comments):

```
[global]
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    server role = standalone server
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    unix password sync = Yes
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    dns proxy = No
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend = tdb

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    create mask = 0700
    printable = Yes
    print ok = Yes
    browseable = No

[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers

[public]
    path = /home/public/public
    valid users = public
    read only = No
```

And here's my directory info:

```
total 36K
527845 drwx--x--x 3 public public 4.0K Dec  3 14:45 .
524289 drwxr-xr-x 6 root   root   4.0K Dec  3 13:38 ..
527847 -rw-r--r-- 1 public public  220 Dec  3 13:21 .bash_logout
527848 -rw-r--r-- 1 public public 3.7K Dec  3 13:21 .bashrc
527846 -rw-r--r-- 1 public public 8.8K Dec  3 13:21 examples.desktop
527849 -rw-r--r-- 1 public public  675 Dec  3 13:21 .profile
527429 drwxrwxrwx 2 public root   4.0K Dec  3 14:45 public
```

BTW, sorry, I'm a bit of a noob in Samba. Hope you'll understand.
Thanks in advance,
matemate01

PS: I've done the `smbpasswd -a public` and tried my best to follow this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated%2C%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way%21)

Here's my actual error:

```
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Comment: And how are you trying to connect?

Comment: @psusi Using `smbclient \\\\localhost\public -U public`. It asks for password and then says that error message. Tried with Windows, using the IP address, gives Access Denied error.

Comment: Check the samba log file?  also auth.log.

Comment: @psusi It says `can't open username map /etc/samba/smbusers. No such file or directory`
auth.log says: `pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody`
PS: Still don't know how to fix that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the hostname to something less than 15 characters.
Write this: `netbios name = somethinglessthan15chars` under the globals section in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `smbpasswd` to add the user to the smb database and set their password.

Comment: Already done that. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @ForceMagic, if you had, then you would not be missing /etc/samba/smbusers.

Comment: @psusi: You're losing it: You're showing up on the Low Quality review queue!  **>:-)** (+1 and voted "Looks OK")

Comment: @psusi Alright. Completely purged and reinstalled samba. Now it says `missing /var/lib/samba/usershares/public` I executed [these](http://pastebin.com/7iSzw8q0) things, if this helps. (Though this is not the complete command-line log.) Still, the client connector says the thing declared on the main question.